# Error from phmpMyAdmin when is configured in order to access remote server with local phpMyAdmin client

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

In order to access to a remote database I have edited `config.inc.php` and at the end of it, before the end `?>` I have added :

```
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'HostName:port'; //provide hostname and port if other than default
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'userName';      //user name for your remote server
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'Password';  //password
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';   // keep it as config
```

but when I connect using browser I have this error message:

> Notice in ./libraries/common.inc.php#1204 Undefined variable: i
>
> Backtrace
>
> ./phpmyadmin.css.php#14: require_once(./libraries/common.inc.php)

The versions are:

```
PHP 5.4.16 Development Server
phpMyAdmin 4.4.15.10
MySQL 5.6.32 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

phpMyAdmin works well with local database, without configure `common.inc.php`

In the middle of `common.inc.php` there's this instruction `unset($i)`, but how can I use the i variable a the end of `common.inc.php` if it is no longer available ?

I have initialized i in this way

```
$i=2;
```

now I see a drop down menu with server name, but when I selected one of them it returns to localhost.

Using mysql command to connect to the remote database server and using the same user/password, I can successfully connect to the database server.

On client server I'm using Linux, on remote I'm using Windows 7

I have entered another request regarding the server selection problem only at [phpMyAdmin can't connect to remote sever on Windows 7 from Linux client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44946378/phpmyadmin-cant-connect-to-remote-sever-on-windows-7-from-linux-client/44946906?noredirect=1#comment76870182_44946906)

Comment: i think you miss a line like $i = 0;

Comment: _“but how can I use the i variable a the end of common.inc.php if it is no longer available ?”_ – _why_ do you want to “use it at the end”? If this gets unset deliberately, then there’s probably a reason for that. What keeps you from adding to the server configuration in the place of the config file where that originally happens?

Answer (score 0):

It's a [Notice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef#answer-4261200) that occurs when you access a variable that is not defined. In your case the variable is `$i`.

Define is first as below

```
$i = 0;
```

Then use it in rest of your code.

Comment: If I set $i = 0; before the settings posted before, I don't have error messagge, but I don't see a drop down menu that allow me to choose the database.

Comment: There might be other error in your code or some missing functionality.