# phpMyAdmin can't connect to remote sever on Windows 7 from Linux client

Tags: php, mysql, linux, windows, phpmyadmin

I cannot connect to mysql server on Windows 7 from my phpMyAdmin on Linux machine.

I've configured phpMyAdmin by modifying `common.inc.php`.
I've added at the bottom of `common.inc.php` the following lines:

```
$i=2;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'HostName:port'; //provide hostname and port if other than default
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'userName';      //user name for your remote server
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'Password';  //password
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';   // keep it as config
$i++;
```

I see a drop down menu with remote server listed, but when I selected a remote server phphMyAdmin returns to localhost and it doesn't connect to remote without error messages.

Using mysql command to connect to the remote database server and using the same user/password, I can successfully connect to the database server.

The versions are:

```
PHP 5.4.16 Development Server
phpMyAdmin 4.4.15.10
MySQL 5.6.32 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

The request is initiated from the post 
[Error from phmpMyAdmin when is configured in order to access remote server with local phpMyAdmin client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44944057/error-from-phmpmyadmin-when-is-configured-in-order-to-access-remote-server-with)
where I have entered a request regarding the configuration of phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 0):

Using the port number in the 'host' directive is not supported. Use the '$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port']' directive to indicate the port number. https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_Servers_port

Comment: I'm not using port number, the setting posted is only an example.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved in this way:
put the setting lines after `$GLOBALS['server'] = 0;` with the variable i initialized to 1 ( `$i=1;` ) instead of put them at the bottom of `common.inc.php`.

Comment: Did you use a port number?

Comment: @Marc Delisle I'm not using port number, the setting posted is only an example

Answer (score 0):

You can access the remote server by adding a block of code in your phpmyadmin config file...

```
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
```

try this